# ERROR ReferenceError: RazorpayCheckout is not defined

Tags: angular, angular8, razorpay

Hi I am using razor pay to pay online through web in my project but I am getting error as `RazorpayCheckout is not defined`

[image: error]

```
  declare var RazorpayCheckout:any;

  payWithRazorpay() {
   var options = {
   description: 'Credits towards consultation',
   image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
   currency: "INR", // your 3 letter currency code
   key: "rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag", // your Key Id from Razorpay dashboard
   amount: 100, // Payment amount in smallest denomiation e.g. cents for USD
   name: 'Razorpay',
   prefill: {
    email: 'test@razorpay.com',
    contact: '9990009991',
    name: 'Razorpay'
   },
   theme: {
    color: '#F37254'
   },
   modal: {
    ondismiss: function () {
      alert('dismissed')
    }
   }
 };

var successCallback = function (payment_id) {
  alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
};

var cancelCallback = function (error) {
  alert(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
};

RazorpayCheckout.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
```

}

I have tried this method as referred by some website but most of them are ionic cordova plugin but I need to work in web pages

Comment: check this link 'https://medium.com/@yaseen_nadaf/integrate-razorpay-with-angular-1a7080cf8e79'

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this error when trying to test on a web browser. Solution is to build an APK of the app and use an emulator or try the APK in a mobile device.